# VSTS release errors on "IIS Web App Manage" step with AppCmd "Not enough storage is available to process this command."

Tags: azure-devops, appcmd

Have a simple two-step release definition in Visual Studio Team Services / VSTS based on the "IIS Website Deployment" template set to configure an application pool (v4, integrated, application pool identity) and website (http, 192.168.0.xxx LAN IP, port 80, valid hostname) which is throwing an error I've struggled to find any details on.  Isolated the issue to some AppCmd parameters but can't seem to remove them via the step settings.

Deploying out to a 2008 R2 target via VSTS agent v2.127.0 which installed without any issues but AppCmd consistently fails on the "IIS Web App Manage" step (after reconfiguring the application pool, creating a directory etc. without problems) then exits with code 8

> hresult 80070008, Failed to commit configuration changes.  Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Full log below but this line causes the error

> "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"Example - Website Name" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"Example - AppPool Name" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\Test\Example - Website Name" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:

Running this directly on the target produces the same error, if I strip the blank username & password parameters it works.  Checked we're not trying to set credentials and combinations of the authentication settings against the website and these two parameters won't either dissappear or format in a way which doesn't throw an error.

Tried searching for similar questions and it's lead nowhere, restarted the target in case it was a memory issue, even tried building a website-only step but the error remains.

```
##[section]Starting: Configure IIS AppPool & Website
==============================================================================
Task         : IIS Web App Manage
Description  : Create or update a Website, Web App, Virtual Directories, and Application Pool
Version      : 0.5.4
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839731)
==============================================================================
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list apppool /name:"Example - AppPool Name"
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set apppool /apppool.name:"Example - AppPool Name" -managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 -managedPipelineMode:Integrated -processModel.identityType:ApplicationPoolIdentity
APPPOOL object "Example - AppPool Name" changed
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"Example - Website Name"
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  add site /name:"Example - Website Name" /physicalPath:"D:\Test\Example - Website Name"
SITE object "Example - Website Name" added
APP object "Example - Website Name/" added
VDIR object "Example - Website Name/" added
##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"Example - Website Name" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"Example - AppPool Name" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\Test\Example - Website Name" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
SITE object "Example - Website Name" changed
ERROR ( hresult:80070008, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.  

Not enough storage is available to process this command.

 )
##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '8'.
##[section]Finishing: Configure IIS AppPool & Website
```

Comment: Try to call appcmd.exe through PowerShell on target machine task and check the result.

Comment: Struggling to reformat the AppCmd line to run under PS so open to suggestions, however it returns the same error when I manually run AppCmd via the console while logged in locally as Administrator

Comment: I mean strip the blank username & password from command, then try it with   PowerShell on target machine task.

Comment: Again, struggling to format it to run under PS eg.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> & "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set site /site.name:'Example - Website Name' -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:'D:\Test\Example - Website Name'

ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )

Comment: To add - contacted developer support about the issue, it's looking like an issue related to "encryption not working" so looking at resetting the applicationHost.config - will update once I've dug into this a little further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing with MS Developer Support my problem appeared to be an issue with the target server's **applicationHost.config** encryption/security keys complicated by a less-than-useful error message being returned by AppCmd

The easiest way to verify the applicationHost.config being at fault was backing up the current config before reverting to an original, default copy of the applicationHost.config (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) then restarting the W3SVC service - was able to execute the "IIS Web App Manage" step without any issues afterwards.

Unfortunately keeping it reverted wasn't an option, so diffed the two versions of the config and found two keys with different `sessionKey` values in `<configuration><configProtectedData><providers>`

Copied the version of the highlighted keys (`AesProvider` & `IISWASOnlyAesProvider`) from our clean config to the current, restarted the W3SVC service and the same AppCmd line was able to run successfully.

Will continue to monitor as this was only happening on a physical internal development server with many potential ways the applicationHost.config could have accidentally changed while it's been in service - none of which should ever apply to a production system.